Use Airflow to move data from Azure BLOB into Snowflake
I would like to know the best practice for moving data from BLOB to Snowflake for an Airflow POV. Currently, we are using ADF to pull data from source to Azure BLOB, then Snowflake pulls that data into staging via a SnowPipe using a Service Integration to Azure's Event Grid.
Current Flow
Source -> BLOB -> Event Grid + SnowPipe + Stream -> Staging -> Execute Task to MERGE into Final Table
We intend to POV Airflow for the entirety of Source -> Final Table, but my question is with regard to BLOB -> Final Table. If we continue to use EventGrid and SnowPipes, then using Airflow at all in this portion of the flow seems unwarranted.
Questions:
Is there any reason to use Airflow in conjunction with the EventGrid/SnowPipe configuration? What might that look like?
What would the alternative be if we do not use EventGrid? My understanding is we would do away with the SnowPipe and move to Bulk Loading:
BLOB - > COPY INTO staging -> Execute Task to MERGE into FINAL Table
A major downside here is that the SnowPipe is triggered by EventGrid - so we only load files new files. If I Bulk Load, I will need to keep track of files we've already loaded in my process, right?


The Snowflake COPY INTO process keeps track of the files that have already been loaded; you don't need to do this yourself:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-considerations-load#load-metadata
